# How to get the size or average size of the result of a query

Tags: mysql

I would like to perform a preliminary evaluation of the size of the records that i'm going to delete from a specific table in my MySQL db. Basically the idea is to get this table:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE action_date >= '2017-11-5 00:00:00'
```

and then perform an evaluation of the size of that result (in Mb). I already did something similar but for the whole table:

```
SELECT ROUND( ((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) 
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE information_schema.TABLES.table_schema = 'myDb' and TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Do you know how can i perform that operation to the result of a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic math and a boolean expression helps.

```
SELECT SUM(action_date >= '2017-11-5 00:00:00') / COUNT(*) AS factor 
FROM mytable;
```

Then you use the result of this query to multiply with the result of your second query (where you get the size of the whole table).

Comment: I was so focused to do everything in a single query that i didn't thought to this approach